# Is this approach right "If preOrder and Reverse of ( postOrder ) are equal than BST has exactly one child "

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, preorder, postorder

Input: pre[] = {20, 10, 11, 13, 12}
Output: Yes
The given array represents following BST. In the following BST, every internal
node has exactly 1 child. Therefore, the output is true.

Is this statement holds good for the above problem "If preOrder and Reverse of ( postOrder ) are equal than BST has exactly one child"?

Comment: Why do you need this? would it be simpler just to traverse the tree and check for number of children in each node?

Comment: Actually, I was just asking if that's true or not (as its showing no error to me)...thanks anyway for another approach.